# SSO - Central authentication Service (CAS) - for production?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas

Do people use Central authentication Service (CAS) on Banking / financial service projects ? Is it a reliable framework for production use.

**Updated:-**

The user details are stored on Active Directory but it is not related to windows logon.

We have around 5 different related web application (separate wars) which may have common users. We are planing to implement one common web application which takes care of the login mechanism using spring security. And this application would pass the Spring security context to all other web apps which would also use spring security.

Along with this we also use 2 factor authentication.

After making some searches it seems CAS would help to achieve SSO (along with Spring Security) but I am just trying to ensure if it can be used in a Financial services projects production system ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

CAS is a web SSO and it supports Kerberos and SPNEGO. So yes, it can be an Enterprise SSO as well.

CAS is production ready: for a big company, I use it for millions of users and hundred of websites.

I'm not sure to fully agree with the "back channel" / "front channel" stuffs. SAML is a standard for federation so if you have two main organizations with their own SAML IdP, you'll be able to federate identities. For other use cases, I prefer CAS which is far more simple and has a large community with a lot of CAS clients.

Answer (score 2):

I work for a huge company in Germany (not the one currently listed in my profile), with 300k+ eployees. We use CAS for a number of applications but our main strategy is SAML. The main reason for SAML is the "front channel" - you can reliably pass assertions via browser.

This has huge advantages in a large enterprise since very often parts of the network are firewalled so the "back channel" solutions (like CAS) don't always work.

With SAML, you could for instance use a completely external service like Salesforce with your company's SAML identity provider. Almost out of the box.

Please note that my production knowledge of CAS is ~4 years old. I might be wrong about the "back channel" for CAS, please recheck that.

Ok, few further insight related to your question update.

- We use AD as user directory too.
- Our identity provider (basically where you login) implements x-factor auth (SMS and token services).
- We use standard SAML solutions, we don't implement proprietary things.
- Sorry I did not mention it before - I'm not in finance/banking but we have apps in a very wide range of security requirements.
- I know peopla who use CAS in the financial sector. Howere, it's not the subject area that matters, it's seqcurity requirements that matter.
- I have had positive experience with Spring Security in the past, but it is not the tech of choice in the current company (more JBoss).

CAS is surely a good thing and will definitely work. However it's normally not the technology which fails it's how you use it in context. If you don't have extensive experience, in the area, get a consulting or a professional pentest. Too many things can be done "a little bit wrong" and lead to severe consequences.

I'm writing all this - and I'm even not a security professional, I'm an architect who designs these apps to fulfill (among magnitude of other things) their security requirements.

Comment: Many thanks for the useful information. I would check on SAML. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Note there are two major types of Single Sign-On (SSO).

There is what I call "Enterprise SSO" which uses the Mircosoft Active Directoy credentials the user used to log into their workstation to also access other resources like websites using the builtin SSO feature of browsers like IE. The underlying protocol used is Kerberos or NTLMv2 (aka SPNEGO to NEGOtiate Kerberos or NTLMv2). This makes it true "single" sign on because the user only enters their password once when they log into their workstation. There are not many solutions that can do this type of SSO. Obviously IIS with IWA turned on is one.

Then there are numerous other solutions for websites that actually redirect the client to another central website that authenticates the client and then redirects them back to the original site with some kind of token. This type of SSO is commonly used on the Internet (like when you log into stackexchange using your google credentials) but it is also not entirely uncommon in an enterprise environment. It is popular in academic institutions where students use whatever computer they can find and aren't logged in with domain credentials in the first place.

So in an enterprise environment like a bank / financial institution my opinion is that "Enterprise SSO" is the most direct and therefore superior solution. With the non-Enterprise SSO solution the authentication step usually requires a password so it's not really true SSO. You have to log into the workstation and then also login to the SSO central website and then you have access to any sites that participate in that particular SSO solution. And it requires running an extra service.

But don't Google for "Enterprise SSO" because everything is marketed as "Enterprise". Use search terms like "Kerberos", "NTLMv2", "Active Directory" in concert with "SSO" and your server programming environment.

Answer (score 1):

You normally use a SSO inside a large organization. It allows members of the organization to login into any internal application with same credentials with a single place for password management. But in this use case, the organization has full control on the CAS server and can be confident in it.